# how windows media player call third-party Decoder MFT?

Tags: ms-media-foundation, windows-media-player

According the decoder sample in Windows SDK, I realize myself decoder MFT, but there is one question about third-party MFT. I register a amr codec MFT, debug with windows sample code), connect the topology manually, it can play normally. But if I run windows media player, it doesn't play the file include amr codec.

What should I do? Windows media player can call my codec MFT automatically.

Other question is about MERIT like directshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you registering your MFT with `MFTRegister` [as MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#registering_mfts)?

> **Registering MFTs**
>
> When you register a Media Foundation transform (MFT), two types of
>   information are written to the registry:
>
> [...]
>
> To create the MFT enumeration entries in the registry, call the
>   MFTRegister function. You can include the following information about
>   the MFT:
>
> [...]

This is the way to make your MFT discoverable by applications.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I am registering the MFT according the smaple code(decoder), it's the same with MSDN. Also the topoedit.exe can play the file with my amr codec MFT if I connect the my MFT manually. I research the question on the internet. Someone said the third-party MFT only used by the third-party himself player app. So I want to know is it sure? and why the windows media player cannot call the third-party MFT just like directshow filter? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

although you might register your decoder MFT for usage with MF components, you have to be aware that you cannot override some default settings for media player (like the decoder MFT used for predefines video formats like mpeg4 or h264).

only custom players might define their preferred decoder MFT using *IMFPluginControl.SetPreferredClsid()*